# How can i print my array using Arrays.toString(reverse) without[]

Tags: java, arrays

how can i print the result without brackets

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();

        }

        int[] reverse =new int[n];
       for (int i = 0; i < reverse.length; i++) {
        reverse[i]=arr[arr.length-1-i];
    }
             in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's like asking how can I print [] without printing []. Don't use Arrays.toString if you don't want the []

Comment: Use String#substring for removing surrounding brackets from your string. Call str = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);

Answer (score 1):

In java8, you can conveniently do any kind of `String` output using `join`, there you will have to do some manual reversing though:

```
String output = String.join(", ", arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the implementation of `Arrays.toString()` so you can't print your array like that.

Although, you can assign it to an `string` variable and then manipulate that string as you desire.

```
String str = Arrays.toString(reverse);
str = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
```